# VBA Set Object within If Statement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So, I created a series of formula on a sheet called Extractor in a workbook called "Processor*". The filename of the workbook "Processor*" will usually vary, having other characters to the right of it. My intention is to copy the range covering all formula I created in a sheet named "Extractor" of the workbook "Processor*", and paste to another workbook "INJ*", with a filename also having variable characters to the right, and specifically to the worksheet named "Table". Upon pasting these formula, it will give results of the different cells i need from "INJ*" based on some conditions I already set in my formula. Please, note that the formula works fine when I do the copy and paste myself. Then I want to copy these results to another sheet on the "Processor*". A sheet called "calculation".
Below is the code I wrote, but I can't seem to get the object defined within the IF statement to work outside the statement. I have several of these files to work with, I will really appreciate your help. Thank you!

```
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet, lrow As Long, lrow2 As Long, rng As Range
    
            
             Dim Ct As Long
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        wb1 = Null
        If WB.Name Like "Processor*" Then
            Ct = Ct + 1
            WB.Activate
            Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
            Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets("Extractor")
            Set sh2 = wb1.Sheets("calculation")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next WB
    If Ct = 0 Then MsgBox "File not open"
            
    
    Dim Ct2 As Long
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If WB.Name Like "INJ*" Then
            Ct2 = Ct2 + 1
            WB.Activate
            Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
            Set sh3 = wb2.Sheets("Manager Report")
            Set sh4 = wb2.Sheets("TABLE")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next WB
    If Ct2 = 0 Then MsgBox "File not open"
                   
                       
        With wb1
        sh1.Range("C38:J42").Copy wb2.sh4.Range("C38")
        End With
        
        With sh4
        .Range("C42:J42").Copy
        sh2.Range("A" & lrow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End With
```

Comment: The workbook where your code is running can always be referred to using `ThisWorkbook`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Dim wbProc As Workbook, wbInj As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet
  Dim sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet
 
  Set wbProc = WorkbookByName("Proc*")
  Set wbInj = WorkbookByName("INJ*")

  If wbProc is nothing or wbInj is nothing then
      msgbox "missing workbook(s)!"
  end if 

  Set sh1 = wbProc.Sheets("Extractor")
  Set sh2 = wbProc.Sheets("calculation")
  Set sh3 = wbInj.Sheets("Manager Report")
  Set sh4 = wbInj.Sheets("TABLE")
                   
  sh1.Range("C38:J42").Copy sh4.Range("C38")
                    
  sh4.Range("C42:J42").Copy
  sh2.Range("A" & lrow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  '....
  '....
```

Function used above:

```
'get an open workbook by [partial] name 
Function WorkbookByName(nm As String) As Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook
    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If WB.Name Like nm Then
            Set WorkbookByName = WB
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next WB
End Function
```

EDIT: you need to specify which workbook to look at for the sheet

```
Function WorksheetByName(wb As Workbook, nm As String) As Worksheet 
    Dim sh As Worksheet 
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets '<<<
        If sh.Name Like nm Then 
            Set WorksheetByName = sh 
            Exit Function 
        End If 
    Next sh 
End Function
```

Then:

```
Set sh4 = WorksheetByName(wbInj, "TABLE*")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Tim. I gave your modification a try. Created the Function you suggested in a new module and then created modified my previous module. Wherever reference is made to the Function, I get a error message "Expected variable or procedure, not module". Please, what do you suggest I do?

Also, if I want only the "Proc*" workbook opened, and expect the vba code to find all other workbook with a filename "INJ*" in the same folder as the "Proc*" file, please do you have a suggestion for me on that?

Comment: Don't name your modules with the same name as a function/sub.

Comment: Oh! I see your point. Let me rectify any of such that I might have.

Comment: You can use `Dir(pathToFolder & "INJ*.xlsx")` to find the files of interest.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That fixed it! You are a lifesaver! Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Sometimes it happens that the sheet "TABLE" can have variable name e.g. "Tables". So, I created a Function that uses the below code:

Function WorksheetByName(nm As String) As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name Like nm Then
            Set WorksheetByName = sh
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sh
End Function

I then reference this worksheet in my main code using:
Set sh4 = WorksheetByName("TABLE*")

I however noticed that the code only works when I run from the workbook containing "Table*"

Comment: Thanks Tim. I wish I could upvote your response a million times. You rock! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long, lrow2 As Long, rng As Range


For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "Processor*" Then
        Set wb1 = wb
        Set sh1 = wb1.Sheets("Extractor")
        Set sh2 = wb1.Sheets("calculation")
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
If wb1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "File not open"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "INJ*" Then
        Set wb2 = wb
        Set sh3 = wb2.Sheets("Manager Report")
        Set sh4 = wb2.Sheets("TABLE")
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
If wb2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "File not open"
    Exit Sub
End If
  

sh1.Range("C38:J42").Copy sh4.Range("C38")
   
sh4.Range("C42:J42").Copy

'''''''''sh2.Range("A" & lrow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

***lrow2*** does not have a value!!!